# AddableSessionFactoryBean exception hbm file not found but files are in lib/*.jar

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat

I am struggling deploying some hiber files I have in a .jar, included in another module. The following are screen-shots for:

1) Maven Build - successful OK

2) Package structure in tomcat/components/ - Ok (files are there, inside jar)

3) Stack trace.

POM-wise, I am adding the resource as we would normally do so... and they ARE being found ok.

```
<!-- ... pom pom pom --> 
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
<!-- ... more pom more pom -->
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

[image: Build, everything OK]

[image: Package structure - everything is there]

[image: Trace]

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that a problem with a class loader.
Spring in `LocalSessionFactoryBean`to load resources uses

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource(mapping.trim(), this.beanClassLoader);
```

And [AdditionalHibernateMappingsImpl](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.sakaiproject.kernel/sakai-kernel-private/10.4/org/sakaiproject/springframework/orm/hibernate/impl/AdditionalHibernateMappingsImpl.java?av=f) uses

```
this.mappingLocations[i] = new ClassPathResource(mappingResources[i].trim());
```

respectivily. Try to debug this classes to see wich class loaders are used.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I found the solution to the problem which was related to how the huge application i am working on distributes components/shared resources in tomcat. You are indeed correct though, but the problem was in the lack of the shared "jar" in tomcat/shared, hence the deploy target of the "jar" which contained the hbm files.

Comment: @Fer I am very glad that you have found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

The component AdditionalHibernateMappingImpl was looking for the hbm resource not relative to its deployment package BUT to the shared resources of the web container (in this case tomcat), so the "jar" that contained the org/.../*.xml deploy target had to be set to "shared" in the pom.

Thanks!